# Setting filter brightness of parent without affecting child element

Tags: javascript, css, css-filters

Is there a way to achieve the effect of setting CSS `filter: brightness()` on an element without it also affecting specific / all (does not matter) child elements?

Consider the following example:

```js
function setBrightness (bright) {
  $('.icon').css('filter', `brightness(${bright})`);
  // None of these work:
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', '');
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', 'brightness(1.0)');
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', `brightness(${1.0/bright})`);
}

window.setInterval(function () {
  let ms = new Date().getTime();
  let bright = Math.cos(2.0 * 3.14 * ms / 3000.0) + 1.0;
  setBrightness(bright);
}, 50);
```

```css
#bar {
  background: #222;
  font-size: 0;
}

.icon {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3);
  width: 36px;
  height: 34px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  /* normally middle but set to top to not obscure background for this example: */
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.icon1 {
  background-position: -141px -54px;
}

.icon2 {
  background-position: -220px -54px;
}

.indicator {
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 50%;
}

.icon1 .indicator {
  background: #a00;
}

.icon2 .indicator {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="bar">
    <div class="icon icon1">
    <span class="indicator">3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon2">
      <span class="indicator">10</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here, I've got a `span` inside a `div` (class `icon`) and I'm setting the filter brightness on the `div`'s like so:

```
$('.icon').css('filter', `brightness(${bright})`);
```

However, I'd like it to *only* affect that background, and not affect the little "indicator" `span`. That is, in the above snippet, the icon should be pulsing but the foreground indicators and their red/green backgrounds should remain unchanged. The only things I thought of to try failed:

```
function setBrightness (bright) {
  $('.icon').css('filter', `brightness(${bright})`);
  // None of these work:
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', '');
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', 'brightness(1.0)');
  // $('.indicator').css('filter', `brightness(${1.0/bright})`);
}
```

Also, it's important that I *not* make changes to the following:

- Cannot change `background-*` CSS properties.
- Cannot change structure of HTML, the `span` must remain a child of the `div`.

I don't actually need a solution that omits *all* child elements, by the way. I only need a single given child (those `span`s) unaffected, as the structure I'm working with does not have multiple children under each `div`; the example is representative. Not sure if that matters.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the opacity of a parent element will always change the opacity of the child element. Sadly there is no way around that. However you can change the HTML structure and absolute position the elements on top of one another, and then only target the elements you want to fade.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function setBrightness (bright) {
  $('.icon').css('filter', `brightness(${bright})`);
}

window.setInterval(function () {
  let ms = new Date().getTime();
  let bright = Math.cos(2.0 * 3.14 * ms / 3000.0) + 1.0;
    setBrightness(bright);
  }, 50);
});
```

```css
#bar {
  background: #222;
  font-size: 0;
 }

 .icon {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3);
  width: 36px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
 }

 .icon-wrap {
  width: 36px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  /* normally middle but set to top to not obscure background for this example: */
 }

 .icon1 .icon {
  background-position: -141px -54px;
 }

 .icon2 .icon {
  background-position: -220px -54px;
 }

 .indicator {
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 18px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
 }

 .icon1 .indicator {
  background: #a00;
 }

 .icon2 .indicator {
  background: #0f0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div class="icon1 icon-wrap">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="indicator">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="icon2 icon-wrap">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="indicator">10</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It is also possible to do with CSS3 keyframes:

```css
#bar {
  background: #222;
  font-size: 0;
}

.icon {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3);
  width: 36px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(200%);
}

.icon-wrap {
  width: 36px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  /* normally middle but set to top to not obscure background for this example: */
}

.icon1 .icon {
  background-position: -141px -54px;
}

.icon2 .icon {
  background-position: -220px -54px;
}

.indicator {
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 18px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.icon1 .indicator {
  background: #a00;
}

.icon2 .indicator {
  background: #0f0;
}

@keyframes fader {
  0%   {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(200%);
  }
  50%  {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
  100% { opacity:1;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(200%);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fader {
  0%   {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
 50%  {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(0%);
 }
 100% { opacity:1;
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fader {
  0%   {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
 50%  {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(0%);
 }
 100% { opacity:1;
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fader {
  0%   {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
 50%  {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(0%);
 }
 100% { opacity:1;
   -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
   filter: brightness(200%);
 }
}
.icon {
   -webkit-animation: fader 3s infinite ease-in;
   -moz-animation: fader 3s infinite ease-in;
   -o-animation: fader 3s infinite ease-in;
   animation: fader 3s infinite ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div class="icon1 icon-wrap">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="indicator">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="icon2 icon-wrap">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="indicator">10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping to not have to move the structure around since I don't have control of the HTML itself, but I suppose it's easy enough to manipulate, I just need to verify that it doesn't break any selectors in other CSS or JS anywhere (it's for [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms)). I'm going to hold out for a while before accepting this to see if any other tricks surface. Btw, might not matter, but this is `filter` rather than `opacity`.

Comment: I have made some changes to the CSS, but not to the JS. It might be a good idea to switch it to opacity, because it isn't supported by any version if Internet Explorer apart from the new Microsoft Edge.